# Make .cpp file to open as default on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-extension, default-settings

I am creating the header files for Arduino, so I created 2 files with `.h` and `.cpp`. the .cpp files open by default with notepad. I want it to look like .h files given in the image. How to change settings in windows 10?

[image]

Comment: I have just re-read your question, and have added something to my answer which might be more accurate to what you wanted to do

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file, select "Open with":

[image: open with header h]

Then select the program you want, making sure you tick the box at the bottom:

[image: how to open file prompt]

Now, every `.h` file you open, will open in the program you selected and you should see the icon change:

[image: new icon]

If you have read this far, I hope it helped. Just to add my 2 cents, I would suggest you look into a more functional bit of software for editing these files instead of `notepad`. My preference would be something like `Notepad ++` to get you started.

**EDIT**: I think I misunderstood what it was that you wanted. Is it the logo you want, or do you want the `.cpp` extension back? If it is the latter, then open an explorer window, click `view` and then tick the box for `File name extensions`

[image: File extensions]